# Address of the Last Byte of Installed Memory

Tags: memory-hardware

I'm a university student currently taking an Assembly and Computer Organization class. On last weeks lab we were given a question:

Suppose that you buy a 32bit PC with 16 MB of Ram. What is the 8-hex-digit address of the last byte of installed memory?

From my understanding you multiply MB (2^20) with 16 (2^4) which gives you 2^24 or 16777216. I subtracted 1 from that number and converted to hex which gives FFFFFF. I then padded to 8 digits and got 00FFFFFF.

This is wrong and I was told the correct answer is 01FFFFFF. Can somebody explain what I did wrong and how that is the correct answer?

Comment: The memory map on a *PC* is not completely standardized and has "holes" for ROM and MMIO

Comment: @harold The class is on 80x86. Our textbook has a problem like this asking for the address of the last byte of 1GB of ram. I worked out this problem the same way and got the correct answer of 03FFFFFF (according to the back of the book), or the total number of bytes minus 1. To me this suggests the book is disregarding the “holes” for ROM and MMIO and just assuming the addresses start at 0 and are successive until the end for simplicity. I was thinking maybe the professor got mixed up and thought the original question regarded 32MB instead of 16MB since 01FFFFFF is (2^25) - 1.